# Can't scroll pager title strip?

Tags: android

I want to implement swiping tabs with title strip with action bar in android.
I have implemented it its working fine except title strip is not scrolling, tab can be scrolled. I want tab title strip to scroll just like play store's title strip.
How can i achieve it...

I have tried the following

main_activity

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v4.view.PagerTitleStrip
    android:id="@+id/pager_title_strip"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:background="#403333"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:paddingTop="4dp"
    android:paddingBottom="4dp" />
```

main.java

```
TabsPageAdapter tabsPageAdapter;
ViewPager viewPager;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    tabsPageAdapter = new TabsPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(tabsPageAdapter);
}
```

tabsPageAdapter.java

```
final int TAB_COUNT = 6;
public TabsPageAdapter(FragmentManager fm){
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int index) {
    switch (index) {
    case 0:
        return new Fragment1(); 
    case 1:
        return new Fragment2();
    case 2:
        return new Fragment3(); 
    case 3:
        return new Fragment4();
    case 4:
        return new Fragment5(); 
    case 5:
        return new Fragment6(); 
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return TAB_COUNT;
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

    switch (position) {
    case 0:
        return "Frag 1";
    case 1:
        return "Frag 2";
    case 2:
        return "Frag 3";
    case 3:
        return "Frag 4";    
    case 4:
        return "Frag 5";
    case 5:
        return "Frag 6";
    }
    return "Not Set";
}
```

Comment: Should not your ViewPager be inside the PagerTitleStrip in xml layout?

Answer (score 0):

this is how i used the view pager :

xml code:

```
   <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/pager_contacts">
 <android.support.v4.view.PagerTitleStrip
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:id="@+id/title_contacts_groups"
         android:layout_gravity="top"
         android:paddingTop="4dp"
         android:background="#33EE34"
         android:paddingBottom="4dp">

 </android.support.v4.view.PagerTitleStrip>
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

calling code:

```
 viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager_contacts);

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        viewPager.setAdapter(new FragmentContactAdaptor(fragmentManager));
```

Comment: yeah its working now.. i had navigation widgets too in the same file which caused a conflict due to which entire screen was freezing and no click was noticed.. once i removed that things are going well

Comment: used library https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip and its working fine